# ggplot legend from scratch

Tags: r, ggplot2

I should be able to do this but I'm at a loss. Given the (ugly) plot below, how can I make a legend with three lines labelled as "CI 90", "CI 95", "CI 99"  and colored as `my.cols[3:1]`. I'd prefer not reshaping the data (`foo`) at all. Many thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)
foo <- tibble(name = letters[1:2],
              ci90lwr = c(0.8, 0.9),
              ci90upr = c(1.2, 1.3),
              ci95lwr = c(0.7, 0.8),
              ci95upr = c(1.3, 1.4),
              ci99lwr = c(0.6, 0.7),
              ci99upr = c(1.4, 1.5))
my.cols <- rainbow(3)
foo %>% ggplot() +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x= name,
                             xend = name,
                             y= ci90lwr,
                             yend = ci90upr),
               size=5,col=my.cols[3]) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x= name,
                             xend = name,
                             y= ci95lwr,
                             yend = ci95upr),
               size=3,col=my.cols[2]) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x= name,
                             xend = name,
                             y= ci99lwr,
                             yend = ci99upr),
               size=1,col=my.cols[1]) +
  labs(y="Estimate",x="Group") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each hue value in `my.cols` a name, so ggplot can map the values in the aesthetic "colour" to the hues in `my.cols`.

```
names(my.cols) = my.cols
```

To get a legend for the colours you need to have colour as an aesthetic in each `geom_segment()`.

```
foo %>% ggplot() +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x= name,
                             xend = name,
                             y= ci90lwr,
                             yend = ci90upr,
                             colour = my.cols[3]),
               size=5) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x= name,
                             xend = name,
                             y= ci95lwr,
                             yend = ci95upr,
                             colour = my.cols[2]),
               size=3) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x= name,
                             xend = name,
                             y= ci99lwr,
                             yend = ci99upr,
                             colour = my.cols[1]),
               size=1) +
  labs(y="Estimate",x="Group") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = my.cols,labels = c("CI 99", "CI 95", "CI 90")) +
  labs(colour = "Colour Variable")
```

To do a custom mapping (i.e. not the default ggplot colours) you use the `scale_colour_manual()` function, and specify values as a vector of colours, with each hue given a name which associates to the aesthetic. You can also do custom labels and a custom title.